# Succinctly calculate differences between all datetime columns in a row

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have implemented the code to identify the Datetime columns and convert them into DateTime.

```
def func(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'object':
            try:
                df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
            except ValueError:
                pass
        if df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]':
            df = df.diff(axis=1)
            return df
```

I want to make new columns using these date columns which are the difference between these columns taking 2 at a time. (for instance if there is date1, date2, date3 columns, output should be like date1-date2, date2-date3, date1-date3). How can it be implemented? I have tried using diff() but I need a concise answer?

Comment: did you have a look at [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)?

Comment: What diff() does is it gives the difference between consecutive rows, I want the difference between the DateTime columns. Like 1st Date Column-2nd Date Column and 2nd-3rd and 3rd-1st Date So On...